# How to assign parameter value to self?

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to assign a function parameter into `self` directly?

The code below is an example of what I'd like to achieve.

```
class SomeClass:
    def some_function(self, key)
        self.<key> = 1
```

I managed something similar for a param keyword using:

```
**{key: val}
```

But can't work out how to do something similar for `self`

Comment: Is `some_function()` a method of a class? I can't see a reason to use `self` as an input parameter otherwise.

Comment: It would be, it's pretty much psuedocode to clarify my question but I have added the class definition for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setattr` and pass the key as a string

```
class SomeClass:
    def some_function(self, key, value):
        setattr(self, key, value)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the answer!